# Javascript - Get child's text value

Tags: javascript, html, dom

How can I get the text value from an elements's child?

Say I have this code on a page:

```
<div class='geshitop'>
  &#91; CODE &#93; &#91; <a href="#" onclick="javascript:copy(); return false;">PLAIN-TEXT</a> &#93;
</div>
<div class='geshimain'>
  <pre><div class="text" style="font-family:monospace;">Code goes here...</div></pre>
</div>
```

The function `copy()`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function copy() {
    var text = this.parent.getElementsByName("text");
    var code = text[0].value;
    var popup = window.open("", "window", "resizeable,width=400,height=300");
    popup.document.write("<textarea name='code' cols='40' rows='15'></textarea>");
    popup.code.value = code;
}
```

How would I go about getting that child's data: the `<div class "text">`. How can I get that from the parent?

---

I'm still having problems. If there is two codeboxes on one page, then it does not work. Remember, I am unable to use ID's. It must be classes.

If I was able to use jQuery this would be easy.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

Change your HTML slightly.  The "javascript:" prefix isn't necessary inside an onclick handler.  Also, pass a reference of "this" to your copy function:

```
<div class='geshitop'>
  &#91; CODE &#93; &#91; <a href="#" onclick="copy(this); return false;">PLAIN-TEXT</a> &#93;
</div>
<div class='geshimain'>
  <pre><div class="text" style="font-family:monospace;">Code goes here...</div></pre>
</div>
```

Having done that, alter your copy function to accept the new parameter.  Then you just have to locate the correct node.  From the question, I think you are looking for the next <div class="text"> that is a child of the <div class="geshimain"> that is the next sibling of the parent node that contains the link that was clicked.  This function should accomplish that:

```
function copy(node) {
    node = node.parentNode; // <div class="geshitop">

    // Loop over adjacent siblings, looking for the next geshimain.
    while (node.nextSibling) {
        node = node.nextSibling;
        if (node.nodeName === 'DIV' && node.className === 'geshimain') {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!node) {
        throw new Error("Could not locate geshimain");
    }

    // Locate the <div class="text">
    node = (function () {
        var divs = node.getElementsByTagName('div');
        for (var x = 0; x < divs.length; x++) {
            if (divs[x].className === 'text') {
                return divs[x];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }());

    if (!node) {
        throw new Error("Could not locate text");
    }

    node =
    '<textarea name="code" cols="40" rows="15">' + node.innerHTML + "</textarea>";
    popup = window.open("", "window", "resizeable,width=400,height=300");
    popup.document.write(node);
    popup.document.close();
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Ok, Firebug gave me this error: cannot access optimized closure
file:///C:/Users/James/Documents/My%20Web%20Sites/javascript_code_box_popup.html#
Line 25

Comment: Ok, I kind of fixed it by removing the extra () at the end of the node function. Now it returns undefined.

Answer (score 8):

Get a reference to the node you want to retrieve text from and try:

```
someNode.firstChild.nodeValue
```

When you have a node like this:

```
<span>Here is some text</span>
```

You're actually looking at two nodes, a span node which has a text node child. In DOM, that text node child's nodeValue is "Here is some text"

Answer (score 1):

put an ID on the  tag you want to get its data from.

this way will only grab the first child of the div node:

```
function copy(){
     var text = document.getElementById( "YOU_TAG_NAME" ).firstChild;
     //do stuff
}
```

this will grab all of the data in the node, but don't do this unless you have control over what goes into that div tag:

```
function copy(){
     var text = document.getElementById( "YOU_TAG_NAME" ).innerHtml;
     //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Using innerHtml may not be what you want: if there are any entities, they are going to come out in encoded form (&amp;).  It sounds like you will want the text content instead.  Getting this will vary by browser, but try something like this:

function innerText(node) {
var s = node.textContent;
return (s === undefined) ? node.innerText : s;
}

Comment: Chris, I need a childs child child.

Answer (score 0):

To clarify: Are you trying to get the css from the "text" class to display?

Just a thought, you could try using `id` attributes to get what you need.

Comment: This is a mod for IPB, changing it to an id wont help.